# How to use the default material UI palette colours?

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular9

How can you use the default colours supplied by Angular Material UI in your own components sass file?

I have my own info display component and I simply want to set the colours of the component to whatever the current primary and accent colours are, however everything I find relates to "themeing" and I don't want to theme I just want to use the existing colours as supplied?

I am using the latest Angular 9.

Answer (score 1):

When using Material 2 or above, It can be a little tricky to figure out how to use the $primary, $accent and $warn colors in your components’s Sass files. This is the easiest way I have found:

Make a standard styles file (`variables.sass` for exemple in the main folder) :

```
// Import material theming functions
@import '~@angular/material/theming'

// Copy the palettes from your selected theme (usually theme.sass).
$app-primary: mat-palette($mat-grey)
$app-accent:  mat-palette($mat-light-blue)
$app-warn:    mat-palette($mat-pink)

// Create your Sass color vars (will be available in all the project)
$primary: mat-color($app-primary)
$accent: mat-color($app-accent)
$warn: mat-color($app-warn)
```

**in `your.component.scss` :**

```
// Import variables.sass to the component's sass file where you want to use it.
@import "~variables.sass"
.selected 
  background-color: $accent
```

Don’t forget to include the theme.scss in the `.angular-cli.json` file:

```
{
...
  "apps": [{
  ...
  "styles": ["_variables.scss"]
  }]
  ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, this is pretty much what I've done however it seems a little odd that you can't somehow just directly fetch the primary, accent and warning colours directly as with this solution you still need to hard code the colour values in the variables.sass file.